# Fields for not working with nested attributes rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

For some reason fields_for is not showing my nested attribute text boxes. I have followed the guide on how to get it to work but still zero luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*The strange part of this is I had working using Oracle as a db then I switched to Sqlserver and now it doesn't work.

Here is my Entry modle

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  include WorkorderTranslator
  belongs_to :release
  belongs_to :session
  belongs_to :sheet

  has_many :stm_entries, :dependent => :destroy

  attr_protected :id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :stm_entries

class StmEntry < ActiveRecord::Base


  self.primary_key = 'id'

  belongs_to :entry

  attr_protected :id
```

Here is my view

```
-if current.stm?
  -e.stm_entries.each do |stm|
    %tr{:id => (stm.editable == true ? 'target' : '') }
      %td.b.trace-table= e.trace_number
      =render "heat_form", :entry => e, :f => f
      -if stm.editable == true

    =f.simple_fields_for :stm_entries, stm do |ff|
      %td.b.trace-table{:style => 'padding-top:3px;'}
        = ff.input :date, :as => :string, :readonly => true, :input_html => {:style => 'width:90%;', :value => (ff.object.date.nil? ? Date.today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") : ff.object.date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")), :placeholder => 'Date', :class => 'floatlabel'}, :label => false
      %td.b.trace-table{:style => 'padding-top:3px;'}
        = ff.input :user, :readonly => true, :input_html => {:style => 'width:90%;', :placeholder => 'User ID', :class => 'floatlabel'}, :label => false
      %td.b.trace-table{:style => 'padding-top:3px;'}
        = ff.input :splices, :label => false, :input_html => {:style => 'width:90%;', :placeholder => 'Splices', :class => 'floatlabel'}
```

Comment: what is stm?  can you show the rest of this form in your question

Comment: I added the rest of my from to the original question @David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when I switched DB's (I was on Oracle moved to SqlServer) I manually created my tables. In doing something messed up(Foreign key, primary key issues). So I just did a rake db:migrate and presto it works.